# get exact match when checking is string is contained is line

Tags: python

I would like to find exact match for items from tuple. Why does my code return True for all lines? I want it to return false. Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

```
test1.xml - 
<field1ff>1</field1ff>
<field1ff>1</field1ff>
<field2ff>1</field2ff>
<field2ff>1</field2ff>




fields_to_find = {"<field1>","<field2>"}

file = open("test1.xml", "r")
for line in file.readlines():
    if (s in line for s in fields_to_find):
        print("true")
```

Comment: if "myString" in array:
   print("true")
else: 
   print("false")

Comment: `if any(s in line for s in fields_to_find)`

Comment: XML is a structured format and should not be processed like that `for line in file.readlines():`. Use a proper xml/html markup parser

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a generator object to your if statement, for which the boolean evaluation is `True`:

```
bool((s in line for s in fields_to_find))
```

Returns:

```
True
```

Instead, IIUC you can use `any()` and pass your generator:

```
any(s in line for s in fields_to_find)
```

Returns:

```
False
```